# What is a "grinding generator"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence, "Over the sound of roaring engines, rushing air vents and grinding generators, a dog barks." what does "grinding generators" mean?

Comment: *Grinding* here is a participial adjective, paralleling *roaring* and *rushing*. A generator is a machine which generates electricity; it has parts which move at great speed, and this motion may produce a *grinding* sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Grinding* in this context is a description of a noise – same as *roaring* and *rushing*.

[One dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=grinding&ls=a) defines this word to mean "making a sound of one hard thing moving against another," and one way it's often heard in English is with the expression "grinding gears," which refers to machinery gears, or the gears of a transmission.

If the gears in this case were automobile transmission gears, a grind might sound like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yturC61EYFQ). However, based on the rest of the sentence, I'm more inclined to think the grinding noise in this case is more incessant, like on [this tractor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgYsy881tMQ).

The generators have gears; they are making a lot of noise. Evidently, that is one very loud canine.